# creating an animated logo completly from text with html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm new in HTML/CSS world, and just started my first project, so i need some help :) I'm trying to create temporary "coming soon" page, that has only company logo that is made of Company Name, and short 4-word Description that goes directly under Company paralel with last 4 letters.. Company Name font is diferent and way larger than Description.. animation needs to raplace that Description with Coming Soon message.. once i group that all togeather i have a problem positioning it in center of a browser and to be responsive.. i'm usin h1 for Company Name and p for Description and message..

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out your problem into 2 main parts,  Font Sizes and Responsive elements, tell me if any other problem is required.

Firstly, The use of `h1` element is not encouraged, you should be using `font-size:10px` as that can give out much more option Css Trick had made a great article on it:https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/

Secondly, Responsive element that needs to be always in middle can be made with `margin: auto;` or `text-align: center;`.

Again, W3School had some pro tip on it:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Hope this can solve your problem and good lucking on learning Webpage making!

Comment: Tnx for your answer.. it worked just after replacing h1 and just 2 or 3 more margin, and paddind adjustments